# Positioning of pics

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw two pics, the second pic should be below the first one. This is what I have currently:

[image: Output]

How can the second pic receive the same x coordinate as the first pic?

Code:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    pics/vhsplit/.style n args = {3}{
        code = {
        \node (A) at (0,0) {#1};
        \node[anchor=south west] (B) at (A.east) {#2};
        \node[anchor=north west] (C) at (A.east) {#3};
        \node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, draw, rounded corners, fit=(A)(B)(C)] (-box) {}; 
        \draw (B.north west) -- (C.south west)
              (B.south west) -- (C.north east);
        }
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic (a) {vhsplit={a}{2.0}{6.0}};
\pic[below=10mm of a-box.south] (b) {vhsplit={b}{-3.0}{-4.0}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add \usetikzlibrary{positioning} to your preamble and have a look into the big tikz manual, which provides many examples. E.g. you could place a node [below] an other.

Comment: Please remember testing your examples :) It also requires `fit`.

Comment: Not sure if this depends on the contents of the nodes, but see if `\pic[below=10mm of aA.south] ...` works.

Comment: @MS-SPO the second pic already has `[below=10mm of a-box.south]`

Comment: @TorbjørnT. tnx, this leads to a slightly better result, but the second pic is still not perfectly centered below the first pic

Comment: Ok. However, if I get it right, the positioning library was missing beforehand. Good you added it.

Comment: The pics aren't as smart as the nodes. It's always the pic's origin that gets placed at the specified location. If that's all you need it might be easier to use normal (multipart) nodes and maybe `tabular` inside the node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pics aren't as smart as the nodes. It's always the pic's origin that gets placed at the specified location.

If this is all you need it might be easier to use a normal node with a  `tabular` inside the node. Here are three approaches:

1. Normal text and a tabular with two rows and one column
   → `vhsplit`
2. One tabular with two rows and two column where `#1` is put in a `\multirow`
   → `vhsplit'`
3. A [`rectangle split` shape](https://tikz.dev/library-shapes#pgf.rectangle:split) from the `shapes.multipart` library, again with a tabular as in 1.
   → `vhsplit''`

Since the lines of the tabular needs to be touching the node's border, I'll set the `inner sep`s (default .3333em) to zero and insert that space at the appropriate places again.

The vertical placements of the left part is a bit variable, choose the one that fits your use-cases the best (the solutions are colored red/green/blue in this order and layed on top of each other with `opacity=.3333`):

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
  vhsplit/.style n args={3}{% text and a tabular
    shape=rectangle, draw, rounded corners, inner sep=+0pt,
    node contents={%
      \setlength{\tabcolsep}{.3333em}%
      \hspxsep#1\hspxsep
      \begin{tabular}{|l@{\hspxsep}}
        \vstysep$#2$\\\hhline{|-}
        \vstysep$#3$%
      \end{tabular}}},
  vhsplit'/.style n args={3}{
    shape=rectangle, draw, rounded corners, inner sep=+0pt,
    node contents={% multirow in a tabular
      \setlength{\tabcolsep}{.3333em}%
      \begin{tabular}{l|l@{\hspxsep}}
        \multirow{2}{*}{#1} &
        \vstysep$#2$\\\hhline{~|-}
        & \vstysep$#3$%
      \end{tabular}}}}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\tikzset{
  vhsplit''/.style n args={3}{
    shape=rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal, rectangle split parts=2,
    draw, rounded corners, inner sep=+0pt,
    node contents={% two nodeparts and a tabular
      \hspxsep#1\hspxsep\null
      \nodepart{two}\setlength{\tabcolsep}{.3333em}%
      \begin{tabular}{l}
        \vstysep$#2$\\\hline
        \vstysep$#3$
      \end{tabular}}}}
\newcommand*\hspxsep{\hspace{.3333em}}
\newcommand*\vstysep{\rule{0pt}{1.0333em}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node             (a) [vhsplit={a}{ 2.0} {6.0}];
\node[below=of a] (b) [vhsplit={b}{-3.0}{-4.0}];

\tikzset{xshift=2cm}
\node (a)         (a) [vhsplit'={a} {2.0} {6.0}];
\node[below=of a] (b) [vhsplit'={b}{-3.0}{-4.0}];

\tikzset{xshift=2cm}
\node             (a) [vhsplit''={a} {2.0} {6.0}];
\node[below=of a] (b) [vhsplit''={b}{-3.0}{-4.0}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
    
    \tikzset{
        pics/vhsplit/.style n args = {3}{
            code = {
                \node (A) at (0,0) {#1};
                \node[anchor=south west] (B) at (A.east) {#2};
                \node[anchor=north west] (C) at (A.east) {#3};
                \node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, draw, rounded corners, fit=(A)(B)(C)] (-box) {}; 
                \draw (B.north west) -- (C.south west)
                (B.south west) -- (C.north east);
            }
        }
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}{scale=3} % <-- changed
        \pic (a) {vhsplit={a}{2.0}{6.0}};
        \pic[xshift=0cm,yshift=-1cm] (b) {vhsplit={b}{-3.0}{-4.0}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

**OUTPUT**:

[image]

Comment: One definitely wants minus signs and not hyphens.